# How to split the text in a column after every second comma in r

Tags: regex, r

I have a column in a dataframe that is made up of rows containing values like

```
SNORD55,RNA5SP47,RNU5F-1,RPS8,RNU5E-6P,SNORD38A,SNORD38B,RNU5D-1,SNORD46,KIF2C,NASP,ZSWIM5,LINC01144,OSTCP5,GPBP1L1,RPS15AP11,BEST4,HMGB1P48,HPDL,CCDC17,AKR1A1,MRPS17P1,TMEM53,HECTD3,UROD,TOE1,TESK2,BTBD19,MUTYH,PTCH2,TCTEX1D4,PLK3,CCDC163P,PRDX1,CCNB1IP1P1,EIF2B3,MMACHC,C1orf228
```

I would like to have a new line every second comma.

I have tried the following:

```
df.l$hgnc_symbol<-sub("([^\\,]*\\,[^\\,]*\\,)","\\1\n",df.l$hgnc_symbol)
```

but this only splits the line after the first two commas and not afterwards.

Comment: Use `gsub` instead of `sub`

Comment: workaround: 1. spliting at every comma 2. put pairs of two elements together.

Comment: @DavidArenburg gsub doesn't work with this pattern. Suspect the pattern is the issue not the function

Comment: What do you mean? It inserts `\n` after every second comma, isn't this exactly what you need?

Comment: Apologies @DavidArenburg. It does work. Suggest posting as an answer? Maybe explain why gsub works instead of sub?

Comment: I think you can use `gsub("(,[^,]*,)", "\\1\n", df.l$hgnc_symbol)`.

Comment: It's pretty self expiatory in the documentation of `?gsub` : "*The two *sub functions differ only in that sub replaces only the first occurrence of a pattern whereas gsub replaces all occurrences*". You could post it as your own answer as you did all the hard work while I just RTFM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DavidArenburg mentioned.  I just needed to add gsub instead of sub

Answer (score 0):

workaround: 1. spliting at every comma 2. put pairs of two elements together.

```
x <- "SNORD55,RNA5SP47,RNU5F-1,RPS8,RNU5E-6P,SNORD38A,SNORD38B,RNU5D-1,SNORD46,KIF2C,NASP,ZSWIM5,LINC01144,OSTCP5,GPBP1L1,RPS15AP11,BEST4,HMGB1P48,HPDL,CCDC17,AKR1A1,MRPS17P1,TMEM53,HECTD3,UROD,TOE1,TESK2,BTBD19,MUTYH,PTCH2,TCTEX1D4,PLK3,CCDC163P,PRDX1,CCNB1IP1P1,EIF2B3,MMACHC,C1orf228"
y <- matrix(strsplit(x, ",")[[1]], , 2, byrow=TRUE)
paste(y[,1], y[,2], sep=",")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with regular expressions, what about this?

```
df.l$hgnc_symbol<-gsub("([\w-]+,[\w-]+),","\\1,\n",df.l$hgnc_symbol)
```

[Example here](https://regex101.com/r/qN0fL8/1). (164 steps)

Note that this is slower than your initial regex. As David Arenburg pointed out, you just need to use [`gsub`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/sub) instead of `sub`.

Final note: [stribizhev's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34018101/how-to-split-the-text-in-a-column-after-every-second-comma-in-r/34018465#comment55792073_34018101) is probably the best way to go.